# UIWebView API Deprecated , Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store

**I'm currently getting the Warning in the subject line.**

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

```
My Cocoapod version is --version
```

One of my framework `Bolts` was using UIWebview so I upgraded to `Bolts-Swift` and also verified in my project none of any `framework or Lib` using `UIWebview`

Still, I am getting mail of warning from APPLE `ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting`

**Here is a list of my Used `pods`**

```
def generic_pods
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'PullToRefresher'
  pod 'Parchment'
  pod 'SJSegmentedScrollView'
  pod 'ZXingObjC'
  pod 'EFInternetIndicator'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'NotificationBannerSwift'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'EasyTipView'
  pod 'FCAlertView'
  pod 'Popover'
  pod 'Bolts-Swift'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed `UIWebview`  from `.readme` file and other text files of the framework, actually framework are not using it `UIWebview` but have mentioned about `UIWebview` in the text file.

I have used below command to find in the project where used `UIWebview`

1. `open command line tools`
2. `grep -r UIWebView "/Path of your project ..."`